# Will changing git remote affect the rest of the team?

Tags: git

I have a repo I cloned from the master and have made changes tp. I've been told today to start a new repo and push to that, I know I can use the following in Git Shell:

```
cd old repo
git remote set-url origin newurl.git
git push -u origin master
```

But what I don't know, due to lack of experience in teams is whether or not this changes the remote for everyone or just me. If so, how can I send my old repo and changed code to a new repo without affecting the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will just set your own remote of `origin` to `newurl.git` for you're local git configuration.

All this really is doing is changing the following configuration file within `./.git/config`

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = newurl.git
```

For more details see https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Answer (score 0):

As other developers are working on `old-repo` they all need to change `origin` with your `new repo origin`.

If you create a new-repo & send your changes to that new-repo. Other developers can `clone the new-repo` or, change their `origin` as like you.